# how to check if the list is palindrome in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, palindrome

I want to test this list whether it's palindrome or not by comparing first element with last element , second element with before the last element and so on

```
(setq l '(1 5 7 8 8 7 5 1))
(defun f (l)
  (cond ((null l) 0)
        ((atom l) l)
        (if       (equal (car l) (car(cdr l))))
```

Comment: False in LISP is `nil`, True is anything else but it's common to use `t`. `0` and `l` where `l` is an atom but not `null` are both true. The last `if` compares the first element with the next. A way to do this would be to reverse the argument then compare those.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a reason for this way of comparing them? If not, it would be easier to use the `reverse` function:

```
(defun palindrome-p (l)
  (equal l (reverse l)))
```

Comment: Or simply `(equal l (reverse l))` also evaluates to either `t` or `nil` so the `if` is redundant.

Comment: @Sylwester [**equal**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm) returns a generalized boolean, so if the list isn't a palindrome, you'll get **nil**, but if it is, you could get anything (except **nil**).  I expect you'd either get **T** or one of the arguments, but there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: @Pascal If you want to guarantee that **palindrome-p** returns either T or NIL, you actually need something like your original version.  **equal** isn't guaranteed to return T or NIL, but rather a generalized boolean.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Even if the spec says so it would be strange if actual implementation did use anything else than `t`. The reason is that `(equal nil nil) ; ==> true` and cannot use the arguments and when comparing structure comparing `nil` is common in the end of the lists. I think an optimizing compiler might use this to eliminate the need for `t` as a symbol using anything but `nil` as it's generalized true, but I guess I have to make that compiler myself :-p

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I assume that the comments are enough, as it works as it is (at least in SBCL, CCL and ABCL on OS X). Or should I edit my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The @Pascal solution reverses the entire list to check if it is palindrome, but this is not necessary. Why not reverse only half of it?

```
(defun palindrome-p (l)
  (let* ((half (floor (length l) 2))
         (secondhalf (reverse (nthcdr half l))))
    (loop for x in l
          for y in secondhalf
          always (eq x y))))
```

This solution (which, I have to admit, is more “common-lispy” and less “lispy”) allocates only half of memory of the solution that reverses the entire list, and in CCL, on my laptop, for long lists uses less then half time.

Comment: Looks like a better solution, but using `eq` instead of `equal` makes it less general, i.e.: `(palindrome-p '("a" 1 "a"))` -> `NIL`.

Comment: I assumed the "unlispiness" came from the use of loop, so I wrote a version with `(every #'identity (mapcar #'eq l secondhalf))` instead of `loop` to compare it with. It does not seem to make sense to use it, though, which brings me to my question: I compared them using time, but I suppose there are better ways that for example run functions multiple times and average the running time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Pascal, you are right for the comparison. An alternative definition could be something like this: `(defun palindrome-p (l &optional (test #'eql)) (let* ...  (loop ... always (funcall test x y)))))` using `eql` which is the standard test for sequences in Common Lisp.

Comment: @Pascal, yes, I was talking about the `loop`. Solutions that uses primitive functions, like `mapcar` etc., are in general less efficient then the use of `loop`, but this is just a generic argument. For what concern testing different solutions, I too use `time` in a naive way to compare functions, by running it three or four times, and I do not know if there are packages that helps in comparing different implementations of an algorithm ([cl-bench](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-bench/) has another objective).

Comment: Thank you!  

I also found [this article](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/Don_0027t-Loop-Iterate.html) that compares iteration constructs and their efficiency interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that conses only half the list:

```
(defun palindrome-p (list)
  (let* ((length (length list))
         ;; The following lists will NOT include the middle element if length is odd
         (half-length (ceiling length 2))
         (tail (nthcdr half-length list))
         (reversed-head (nreverse (butlast list half-length))))
    (equal tail reversed-head)))
```

The thing about this option is that you get two lists of similar length, you don't have to worry about whether iteration stops at the smallest one, and it's easier to adapt and debug later for other purposes.

---

Yet another option that is usually disregarded is to copy the whole list into a vector.  Most implementations take 1 or 2 architecture words (32-bit/64-bit) to represent a `cons`, thus the worst case for a list is:

- `2 × length` words

These same implementations take about 1 to 2 words for the vector's header, plus 1 word per element, thus the worst case for a vector is:

- `2 + length` words

What I mean is, you'll have about the same memory allocation cost for consing half of the list compared to copying the whole list into a vector.

The compromise is to find out when the header is no longer much of an overhead compared to consing and (n)reversing the list, or from accessing the nth element of a not-that-small list.

If this threshold is found, I'd redefine it as follows, making it accept [a sequence](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_a.htm):

```
;; Mere example, I did not research this on any implementation
(defconstant +list-to-vector-overhead-threshold+ 8)

(defun palindrome-p (sequence)
  (if (and (consp sequence)
           (not (null (nthcdr +list-to-vector-overhead-threshold+ sequence))
      (palindrome-p (concatenate 'vector sequence)
      (let ((length (length sequence)))
        (dotimes (i (floor length 2))
          (when (not (equal (elt sequence i) (elt sequence (- length i 1))))
            (return nil)))
        t)))
```

---

PS: Here's some implementations' object sizes found by experimentation (meaning, I might be wrong about these numbers) with 32-bit implementations:

- Allegro CL

  - List: `2 × length` words
  - Vector: `2 + length` words, 2 words aligned (i.e. in 32-bit, 8-byte aligned)
- Clozure CL

  - List: `2 × length` words
  - Vector: `1 + length` words, 2 words aligned (i.e. in 32-bit, 8-byte aligned)
- LispWorks

  - List: `3 × length` words
  - Vector: `2 + length` words
- SBCL

  - List: `2 × length` words
  - Vector: `2 + length` words

Answer (score 0):

```
; Get the reverse of a list
(defun revList (l)
(cond 
    ((null (cdr l)) l)
    (t (append (revList (cdr l)) (list(car l) ) ))
)
)
; Check whether a given a list is a palindrome
(defun palindrome (l)
(cond   ((null l) t)
    ((equal (car l) (car (last l)))(palindrome (cdr (revList (cdr l)))))
)
)
```

This implements a recursive function that returns (t) if a string (represented as a flat list of atoms) is a palindrome and (nil) otherwise. you can use the built-in "reverse" lisp function instead of "revList".

Answer (score -1):

```
(defun palind (l1)
  (if (equal l1 (reverse l1))
      'palindrome
      'no-palindrome))
```